# Import error when using twine and wheel to upload python package to PYPI

Tags: python, upload, pypi, twine

I have a python package ready for distribution on PyPI. To do this I am using `twine` as recommended on the in the Python docs. I have my setup.py file and this previously worked using the `setup.py register upload` command for my previous release.

To upload on to  PyPi I am using:

```
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel
twine upload dist\PyCoTools-2.1.2-py2-none-any.whl  #this was created in the previous line
```

Now, on another computer I try using:

```
pip install PyCoTools
```

and it installs but then:

```
>>> import PyCoTools
```

Gives an import error. I go to the Libs/site-packages and all I see is this:

[image]

i.e. no folder called `PyCoTools`, just the dist info.

and inside that I just have [image]

Which (obviously) doesn't incude the files that are in my package. Could anybody give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you forget to put **init**.py inside your pyCoTools directory ? I had the same issue and I resolved it by adding this file.